# fixing window media center - channel

Tags: windows-media-center

I've gotten my WMC in a bad state. After trying various free tools to enchance WMC with channel editors and the like, it no longer updates the channel guide.

What is required to reset my WMC - can I uninstall/reinstall, or do I need to clear out additional files and registry entries?

Edit - WMC runs fine in other all other ways. It plays video, recorded TV, and live TV - it just won't update the guide.

I think this program http://thedigitallifestyle.com/w/index.php/2011/07/05/windows-media-center-guide-editor-2-0-1/ is what broke the listing.

Comment: I'd try reinstalling the tuner(s), that is, Settings / TV / TV signal / Setup TV signal.  That should install a new/fresh channel list.

Comment: It goes into an endless wait at "Downloading TV Setup Data"

Comment: What tools have you tried will help us to provide you the new solution rather than which have you already used. Also you have not mention what kind of problem you are facing regarding WMC? Does other program runs correctly etc.

Comment: reinstall WMC: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-windows-media-center-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to manually update the guide by running :

```
C:\Windows\ehome\mcupdate.exe -manual -nogc -p
```

Let us know what happens when you try it.

You could try to empty out the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\eHome\`,
to restore the original Live TV guide settings. For details see :
[Clearing Guide Data and Tuner Setup from Windows 7 Media Center](http://www.hack7mc.com/2009/09/clearing-guide-data-and-tuner-setup-from-windows-7-media-center.html)

Otherwise, to reinstall WMC :

1. Go to Control Panel => Programs and Features, and click **Turn Windows Features on/off**. Uncheck Windows Media Center.
2. Reboot.
3. Empty out the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\eHome\`
4. Go again to Programs and Features and enable Windows Media Center again.
5. Run Windows Media Center and do the TV setup.

For more details see : [How To Reinstall Windows Media Center In Windows 7](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-windows-media-center-in-windows-7/) (although it misses out on step 3).

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for accepting my answer. It would also be useful to know which of the above suggestions worked for you.

Comment: I did a re-install - less steps than the manual clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this a few times:

- Start Media Center.
- Run the file `mcupdate.exe` **as administrator** located in the `C:\Windows\ehome\mcupdate.exe` folder.
- Restart Media Center.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

`C:\Windows\ehome\mcupdate.exe -uf`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about 2 months after installing a SiliconDust HomeRun Prime on a 3 year old Windows 7 Dell XPS Studio computer. I solved it by repeating the "Set Up TV Signal" task:

WMC startup page > Tasks > settings > TV > TV Signal > Set Up TV Signal

This process will take 15-30 minutes, so be patient.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run setup TV signal again, set the zip code to another zip code preferably to a town’s zip code near your home then rescan the TV stations again twice.  Then reset the zip code to your zone again and rerun the TV signal setup again twice.  After two months of trying different things this finally worked for me.